# Error building simple Qt5 application

Tags: c++, qt, build, qt-creator, qt5

I installed **Qt 5.0.0** (*qt-mac-opensource-5.0.0-clang-offline.dmg*) on a **Mac OS X 10.7.5** and now I'm trying to compile a "*Hello World*" application using **Qt Creator 2.6.1**.

The build process complains about a directory not found: `/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/qtbase/lib` , followed by several linking errors:

```
clang++ -c -pipe -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I. -I/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/include -I/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/include/QtGui -I/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/include/QtCore -I/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -o main.o main.cpp
clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o hello_qt.app/Contents/MacOS/hello_qt main.o -F/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/lib -framework QtGui -F/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/qtbase/lib -framework QtCore -framework OpenGL -framework AGL
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/qtbase/lib'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)", referenced from:
_main in main.o
"QLabel::QLabel(QString const&, QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)", referenced from:
_main in main.o
"QWidget::show()", referenced from:
_main in main.o
"QPushButton::QPushButton(QString const&, QWidget*)", referenced from:
_main in main.o
"QApplication::exec()", referenced from:
_main in main.o
"QPushButton::~QPushButton()", referenced from:
_main in main.o
"QLabel::~QLabel()", referenced from:
_main in main.o
"QApplication::~QApplication()", referenced from:
_main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [hello_qt.app/Contents/MacOS/hello_qt] Error 1
```

It's important to note that the path `/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/qtbase/lib` is not valid because the directory *qtbase* doesn't exist. The working path is `/Users/karlphillip/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/lib`. I'm not referring to `qtbase` anywhere in my project, so this is probably being added by **qmake**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it turns out, **the invalid `qtbase` path thing is really a Qt bug** originally reported at [QTBUG-28336](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28336).

**The linking problem is due to my project not linking with QtWidgets**, which is something we are going to have to do starting in Qt5. This is accomplished by adding the following line to your **.pro** file:

```
QT += widgets
```

Comment: I tried this, and at first it fixed an immediate compile issue I had a few days ago.  But now the issue has come back.  There must be more to this issue.  I am using OS X 10.7.5, Qt Creator 2.6.2, and Qt 5.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and to be honest im not shure how i managed it to solve.

i think/guess i copied the needed folders from the sources into the matching 'clang_64' folders and that does the job.

soo long zai

Comment: You copied in the qtbase folder?  If so, where did you get it?

Comment: i found the qtbase directory in the 'QtSources'. if you have installed the sources of qt as well, you should find it in the installation directory of your qt installation.

Comment: I cannot find this on the internet or on my local machine.  Would you mind clarifying what 'QtSources' is?  Is it a directory?  Am I missing it because I did not install the correct version of Qt?

Comment: ok i used the name that qt uses in the windows version ...

if you have installed the qt package and selected that you want to 'install source code' you should have a directory under `<QTINSTALLDIR>/5.x.x/Src/` and that should contain the missing `qtbase` directory